# How to redirect these kind of URLs which are formed upon creation of sub domain?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdomain, forum

Here is my website by name `iamfine.com` and `forum.iamfine.com` is its sub domain.

Previously, the forum of `iamfine.com` was accessed by `iamfine.com/forum`, and now it is accessed by `forum.iamfine.com`.

I have not moved the file anywhere. I have just maintained them under the forum directory from the root directory.

I want to redirect all the forum URLs as below:

```
http://iamfine.com/forum/index.php
```

to

```
http://forum.iamfine.com/index.php
```

How can I do this?

I am using Red Hat Linux.

Comment: Future reference: [whathaveyoutried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rewrite the forum directory, but you need to check it isn't already in the subdomain.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(www\.)?iamfine\.com$
RewriteRule ^forum/(.*)$ http://forum.iamfine.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This is assuming your `RewriteEngine` is on, and that you want the 301 redirect.

[Apache Mod_Rewrite Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)